# Django Related Through Models Not Using Soft Delete Model Manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

i am trying to retrieve only rows in a through model that are not deleted but keep getting all rows including the deleted ones.
learnt it's a bug with using `use_for_related_fields` in the model manager according to this link: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17746
i am trying to implement a follow/unfollow system like on social media platforms

below is my code sample

```
class BasicModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        return self.update(is_deleted = True, deleted_at = timezone.now())

    def erase(self):
        return super(BasicModelQuerySet, self).delete()


class BasicModelManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BasicModelQuerySet(self.model, self._db).filter(is_deleted = False).filter(deleted_at__isnull = True)


class BasicModel(models.Model):
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    objects = BasicModelManager()
    everything = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Listing(BasicModel):
    watchers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through = 'Watching', related_name = 'watchers')


class Watching(BasicModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'watching')
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'spectators')
```

sample tables

```
id | user   |
-------------
1  | User A |
2  | User B |

id | listing   |
----------------
1  | Listing A |
2  | Listing B |

# watchings table
id | user   | listing   | deleted_at          | is_deleted |
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | User A | Listing A |                     |            |
2  | User B | Listing A | 2022-02-25 11:07:18 | True       |
3  | User B | Listing B |                     |            |
```

```
listing = Listing.objects.get(id = 1)
# returns Listing A

listing.watchers.all()
# returns two rows [1, 2] instead of just 1
# what i want is to return only User A because User B is deleted

listing.watchers.through.objects.all()
# returns two rows [1, 3], which is wrong because row 3 is not for Listing A
```

how do i get to return only rows that are not deleted for a listing? or do i need to change the design and or not use a through model?

Comment: Add  .filter(is_deleted=False) to your query set.

Comment: please where? because it's already added

Answer (score 0):

1. following will return all the `Users` for **a listing which** are present in your DB, as you are not applying any filter.

```
listing.watchers.all()
```

2. here you seems to make same mistake of not filtering, remember there are entries in DB. you have not deleted them.

```
#listing.watchers.through.objects.all()
listing.watchers.through.objects.exclude(is_deleted=True)
```

Apart from it. what I think wrong is that extra `Watching` table. that could have been meaningful if you would have more fields in that table(though they dont seems to require as you said, it's just follow/unfollow feature)

Comment: still not working as expected. `listing.watchers.through.objects.exclude(is_deleted=True)` returns watchings for other listings a well which is not what i want